# How to properly replace/remove azure private agents

Tags: azure-devops, virtual-machine

I want to replace or possibly remove the private agents in our azure devops instance. I know that I can achieve this by using either the virtual machine scale sets or by containerize. The problem is I don't know which method is most efficient. Since I have never used any of the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the private agents in your Azure DevOps instance in bulk, you can write a script to call the [Pools - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) REST API to loop through your organization  and delete the agents by calling ([Agents - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)) REST API. Of course you must have delete permission to do that.

You can use below PowerShell script to achieve that, but please **NOTE** that you have **set the filter correctly**, otherwise the other agents may be deleted by mistake.

```
Param(
   [string]$orgurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}", 
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "Password/PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get pools ID
$PoolsUrl = "$orgurl/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=5.1"           
$poolresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PoolsUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$poolids = $poolresponse.value.id

Cls

foreach ($poolid in $poolids)
{
 #Get agents in each pool
 $agentsurl = "$orgurl/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$poolid/agents?api-version=5.1"  
 $agentresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $agentsurl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

 #Filter agents，please be sure you have set the filter correctly, avoid accidental deletion 
 $privateagents = ($agentresponse.value | where {$_.name -like 'Private*'})

 $agenturls = $privateagents._links.self.href

 #Delete private agents:
   foreach ($agenturl in $agenturls)
   {
     $deleturl = $agenturl + "?api-version=5.1"
     $deleteresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $deleturl -Method DELETE -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
     Write-Host $deleteresponse
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to properly replace/remove azure private agents

For this issue ,do you mean deleting private agents from azure devops? If so, you can achieve this in the `Agent pools` of organization setting:

[image]

Comment: yup .. The problem is we have a lot of private agents in different instances so I'm looking for a better way to remove them without manually going to each instances

Comment: In addition to removing through web ui, you can also use `config.cmd remove` command and [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), but these two are also not convenient according to your situation.

Comment: ahh I think its possible to create a script that will loop trough our organization and delete the agents using the API ..?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this method is available,the only trouble is that you need to get the PAT of all instances.